# Play sound on link click then redirect

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('swoosh'),
        audio = document.getElementById('a-on-click'),
    clickHandler = function () {
        audio.play();
    }
;

for (var i in links) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
```

For the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="swoosh">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="swoosh">Link 3</a>

<audio id="a-on-click">
          <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The script works like a charm, only activating the sound if the `a` has `class="swoosh"`. However, the problem appears when the link in the `href` is an actual link and not a `#`.

I did some research on SO and Google. I thought that `preventDefault()` would be the solution here, however I'm starting to doubt that because what I want is for the sound file to play and **then** redirect to the location specified in the `href`, not to stop the link functionality entirely. The solution should also only apply to links that have the "swoosh" class.

How is this achievable?

You can find a JSFiddle to play with [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qkuLkqao/21/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault()` in the `clickHandler`, it will block the default behavior of the links with that particular class:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('swoosh'),

  audio = document.getElementById('a-on-click'),

  clickHandler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      window.location = event.target.href;
    });

    audio.play();
  };

for (var i in links) {
  typeof i === 'Number' && links[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" class="swoosh">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="swoosh">Link 3</a>

<audio id="a-on-click">
          <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Docs: [`Event.preventDefault()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

**EDIT 1:** Please use the `audio.addEventListener` from Ben's answer. He's got it.

**EDIT 2:** Changed code in `for` to check if `i` is Number type

**EDIT 3:** Your href is incorrect. Use the one below:

```
  clickHandler = function(event) {
    var href = this.href; // cache href here

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    audio.play();

    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
       window.location = href; // use cached href here
    })
  };
```

Comment: Both answers throw an Uncaught TypeError: links[i].addEventListener is not a function". In my live app yours works better and is closer to what I need but unfortunately after the sound finishes playing and it redirects it does this to "example.com/undefined" and shows a 404 instead of redirecting to the page specified in the link.

Comment: @SporeDev Check my updated code, I have added a check for `links[i]` in the for loop. That should resolve the first error that you mentioned. Your second error is unclear to me. There is some variable that does not have the value you think it has, and hence its giving undefined at the end of that link. Can you provide relevant code to reproduce that issue?

Comment: Not sure what code I could provide. You can check here: sporedev.ro/pleiade/hol.html. Click on the right pointing arrow that has the text "Maya și Asterope" and you'll see that the redirect takes you to domain.com/undefined instead of my actual link target.

Comment: @SporeDev You seem to have solved the issue now, its working in your site. My 2nd edit was incorrect actually, the check needs to be of the typeof i

Comment: Weird. I still don't see it working, I kept trying your scripts and modifying so I'm not sure what worked. When you click the right arrow now it doesn't take you to a 404?

Comment: @SporeDev Please see EDIT 3 above.

Comment: @SporeDev it worked earlier for some reason and now I see the issue again. Basically, `event.target.href` does not have the value you think it has, plus that event is `ended`  event and not the click event

Comment: Also, you dont need to do `stopPropagation()`, if you are doing `preventDefault()` already

Comment: It works now, thank you. Removed stopPropagation() as well.

Comment: `for ... in` isn’t great for interating arrays, which is why you’re needing to check for `number`. `for`, `.forEach` or `for ... of` would all work better.

Answer (score 3):

Rahul's got it; then, wait til the audio finishes and then navigate.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('swoosh'),
  audio = document.getElementById('a-on-click'),
  clickHandler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
          window.location.href = event.target.href;
    })
    audio.play();
  };

for (var i in links) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" class="swoosh">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="swoosh">Link 3</a>

<audio id="a-on-click">
          <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Sorry, the comment was meant for Rahul. :)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent immediate click effect use one of these inside your listener.

> event.preventDefault() || event.stopPropagation();

When you are done playing sound add an event listener for when the sound ends to change the location of the current window.

> window.location = event.target.href;

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('swoosh'),
  audio = document.getElementById('a-on-click'),
  clickHandler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    audio.play();
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
       window.location = event.target.href;
    })
  };

for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, true, true);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" class="swoosh">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="swoosh">Link 3</a>

<audio id="a-on-click">
          <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Your solution works just as well as Rahul's solution but has the same problem. When the redirect takes place it does to an undefined page and throws a 404 instead of redirecting to the address specified in the href.

Comment: Hi, Please Check Now (I have updated Code Further). If have any further issue just let me know we will sort that out.

Comment: Same issue. You can check here: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/hol.html. Click on the right pointing arrow that has the text "Maya și Asterope" and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: No, just click that arrow and see where it takes you.

Comment: It is navigating fine.
the error is just with the wrong URL which is in the console.

Comment: Yes but if you check that arrow (that has the swoosh class) you'll see that the target is https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/outdoor.html not https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/undefined

Comment: I Got The Issue this is because of scope issue you are redirectating in another scope which don't have href property.

Comment: Then how can I solve this? I'm just looking into scope to find a way.